# addClass removeClass w/jQuery for Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-transitions

[**SEE MY ANSWER BELOW**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336991/742030)

I'm implementing my own sliding page transition with CSS using jQuery and having the following issue:

I'm using the addClass method and it works the first time a link is fired to load a page dynamically into the div. When another link is fired, the page loads without the transition.  I figured it was that I need to use the removeClass method but this prevents the transitions from not fireing at all. Iv'e tried various ways of using the two classes but I cant get it to work every time a link is fire.

Any idea to what I have wrong/missing?

EDIT  For those who doesnt under stand the CSS subClass:

> More than one class may be added at a time, separated by a space, to
>   the set of matched elements, like so:

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

[Taken from the jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

thnx.

```
/* --------------- Handle Page Body Loading ----------------- */

function loadBody(target, gotoURL)
{
    $('#' + target)
    .addClass('slide out')
    .load(gotoURL, function (response)
    {
        iniScroll('scrollBody', 'bodyScrollContainer');
    })
    .addClass('slide in')
    removeSlideClass();//WITHOUT THIS, IT FIRES ONLY THE FIRST USE!!
};

function removeSlideClass()
{
    $('#bodyContent').removeClass('slide in');
    $('#bodyContent').removeClass('slide out');
};
```

IF i WRITE THE CODE AS SAID BELOW, IT WORKS EXACTLY THE SAME (jQuery 101);

```
function loadBody(target, gotoURL)
{
    $('#' + target).addClass('slide out');
    $('#' + target).load(gotoURL, function (response)
    {
        iniScroll('scrollBody', 'bodyScrollContainer');
    });
    $('#' + target).addClass('slide in');
    $('#' + target).removeSlideClass();
};

function removeSlideClass()
{
    $('#bodyContent').removeClass('slide in');
    $('#bodyContent').removeClass('slide out');
};
```

the CSS:

```
.out, .in {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 650ms;
}
.slide.out {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
}

.slide.in {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromright;
}
```

Comment: What is `$('#' + target)` doing by it self there. SEems like syntax error or typo

Comment: Do you realize on each *Class call you're making, you're manipulating **2** classes, not just one. `class="slide in"` has both the class `slide` and `in`, not to be confused with something like `slide-in`.  You should put your full code in a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/), I have a fealling you're making quite a few other mistakes.

Comment: in theory that shouldn't cause an error though, javascript doesn't require semicolons

Comment: @elclanrs see edit above. Thnx

Comment: @SpYk3HH  Seed edit above. Thnx

Comment: @masterkrang Thnx for pointing that out - I thought I was the beginer.

Comment: @SpYk3HH See the CSS.  Thats how two or more sub-classes are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Binding the `.addClass('slide out')` method with `webkitAnimationEnd` event,  followed by a return statement, fires the second transition when the first has completed. When this event fires, it removes all classes from the original page. Remembering to unbind the `webkitAnimationEnd` event prevents adding on extra handlers to the new page so the process can start again when we need it. Thus jQuery's `removeClass()` method is not needed.

The new page transition method.

```
/* --------------- Handle Page Body Loading ----------------- */

function loadBody(target, gotoURL)
{
    $('#' + target)
    .addClass('slide out')
    .bind('webkitAnimationEnd', function(){
        $(this).load(gotoURL, function (e)
        {
            iniScroll('scrollBody', 'bodyScrollContainer');
            $('#' + target)
            .toggleClass('slide in')
            .unbind('webkitAnimationEnd');
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

CSS class should not include any spaces...

ie:

slide out, should be slide-out, or slide_out or slideOut

Try removing the spaces and fixing the classes in the css to Match.

Comment: out and in are **SUBCLASSES** of slide. look at the CSS and use your real profile. This methode is how you call on them - it works everywhere in the app or any app that calls on CSS subClasses.

Comment: This is my real profile... If it's a subclass, should it not have a space in the CSS. ie .slide .out instead of .slide.out.